# Does "cp -r" behave oddly in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm working on a bash script to bootstrap a cloud server with the puppet client so that I can create a boot image, but I'm getting weird behavior from a simple "cp -r" where the contents of my source directory are being copied, but the parent directory is not being copied.  For example, if I had /root/puppet/file1, and I issued a `cp -r /root/puppet /opt` command in my bash script, instead of getting /opt/puppet/file1, I'm getting /opt/file1.  However, if I echo the command in my script just before it gets executed, and then copy the output of that echo and run it on the command-line, I then get /opt/puppet/file1 as expected.

Here's my directory structure.

```
mydirectory
    - script.sh
    - assets
        - puppet
            - file1
            - file2
            - file3
```

And here's the snippet from my script

```
#!/bin/bash

### VARIABLE INITIALIZATION
BOOTSTRAP_DIR="/opt/bootstrapping"

# Die with an error message
die()
{
    echo "**** BOOTSTRAPPING FAILED ****"
    echo -e "ERROR:  ${2}"
    exit ${1}
}

# check the return code of the previous command and die if != 0
check_errs()
{
    if [ "${1}" -ne "0" ]; then
        die ${1} "${2}"
    fi
}

# Get the path of the directory from which this script is being executed
SCRIPT_PATH="`dirname \"$0\"`"              # relative
check_errs $? "Could not get the relative path of the executing script"
SCRIPT_PATH="`( cd \"$SCRIPT_PATH\" && pwd )`"  # absolutized and normalized
check_errs $? "Could not get the absolute path of the executing script"

### DEPLOY THE BOOTSTRAPPING FILES
if [ -d "${BOOTSTRAP_DIR}" ]; then
    echo "Removing ${BOOTSTRAP_DIR}"
    rm -rf ${BOOTSTRAP_DIR}
    check_errs $? "Could not remove ${BOOTSTRAP_DIR}"
fi

if [ ! -d "${SCRIPT_PATH}/assets/puppet" ]; then
    die 1 "Can not find ${SCRIPT_PATH}/assets/puppet"
fi

if [ ! -f "${SCRIPT_PATH}/assets/rc.local" ]; then
    die 1 "Can not find ${SCRIPT_PATH}/assets/rc.local"
fi

# This command succeeds, but /opt/bootstrapping/puppet does not exist afterwards.
# Instead I get /opt/bootstrapping/files...
echo "Copying ${SCRIPT_PATH}/assets/puppet to ${BOOTSTRAP_DIR}"
cp -r ${SCRIPT_PATH}/assets/puppet ${BOOTSTRAP_DIR}
check_errs $? "Could not copy ${SCRIPT_PATH}/assets/puppet to ${BOOTSTRAP_DIR}"

echo "Copying ${SCRIPT_PATH}/assets/rc.local to /etc/rc.local"
cp ${SCRIPT_PATH}/assets/rc.local /etc/rc.local
check_errs $? "Could not copy ${SCRIPT_PATH}/assets/rc.local to /etc/rc.local"
```

Can anyone explain why only the contents of my source directory are being copied?  I feel like this is something dumb that I'm not seeing because I'm tired.

**EDIT**

This was definitely a case of me being dumb.  When the script calls `cp -r /root/assets/puppet /opt/bootstrapping`, /opt/bootstrapping does not exist, so cp creates /opt/bootstrapping, and places the sources files into that new directory.  I don't think this question will have much value for anyone in the future.  Unless anyone objects, I'd like to have it removed.

Comment: `cp` is an executable, not a shell-builtin. So `cp -r` will act the same regardless of which shell you're using.

Comment: Yet it is not behaving the same.  If I echo the command I get `cp -r /root/assets/puppet /opt/bootstrapping` which is what the script should be executing.  When I run it outside the script, the directory gets copied, and not just the files.

Comment: Acutally, Sometimes `cp` is aliased to something else. Can you run `alias | grep cp` from a bash prompt and tell us what you get?

Comment: The `check_errs` function is superfluous, you can replace all occurrences of `cmd; check_errs $? "error"` with `cmd || die "error"` which is more elegant and more idiomatic.

Comment: The gyrations to get the absolute path of the script look inefficient and potentially wrong.  Why do you care about the absolute path anyway?  You do not `cd` anywhere within the script so copying by relative path should work fine.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Actually, `type -a cp` is more useful. It will tell you if there's an alias, function or alternative file locations.

Comment: @tripleee This script will be executed by root.  I've lost a server before because a harmless script was modified by a developer and a chmod -R command ran against / instead of the relative directory.  Absolute paths protect against human error in the future.

Comment: @tripleee thanks for the cmd || die suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

On OS X 10.7, the man page for cp says:

```
 -R    If source_file designates a directory, cp copies the directory and the entire subtree connected at that
       point.  If the source_file ends in a /, the contents of the directory are copied rather than the directory
       itself.  This option also causes symbolic links to be copied, rather than indirected through, and for cp to
       create special files rather than copying them as normal files.  Created directories have the same mode as
       the corresponding source directory, unmodified by the process' umask.
```

Note that the option is actually documented as `-R` instead of `-r` but both work.

I tried the following in some directory:

```
mkdir -p tmp1/tmp2/tmp3
mkdir test
cp -r tmp1 test
```

and it works as you'd expect, i.e., test now contains tmp1 and its child directories. Could you tell us more details about the operating system that you're using? Also, have you checked if your system has a non-standard cp?

Comment: The option is documented as `-R` because it's different from `-r`: "Historic versions of the cp utility had a -r option.  This implementation supports that option; however, its use is strongly discouraged,
     as it does not correctly copy special files, symbolic links, or fifo's."

Comment: I've tried both -r and -R and have seen the same behavior.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and am using the stock cp.

Comment: I even tried with and without trailing / and it behaves the same.

Comment: Thanks @CarlNorum for the clarification with the `-R` and `-r`.

Comment: @GregB, I don't have Ubuntu 10.04 LTS to test, but this [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/cp.1.html) is discomforting because the description for the `-r` or `-R` does not contain the same information as that on OS X. Of course, this is not a definitive proof but could this mean that `cp` on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS does not behave as you would expect with the trailing slashes when you use the recursive switch?

Comment: And what is really this `--strip-trailing-slashes` switch for? It looks like OS X has a very different man page than others. However, [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal/) describes what you're expecting `(To understand what "recursively" means, think of it this way: to copy the directory and all its files and subdirectories and all their files and subdirectories of the subdirectories and all their files, and on and on, "recursively")`. Could it be that your cp is aliased to something else?

Comment: OS X is derived from BSD; GNU coreutils (which is what you usually have on Linux) have their own genealogy. Anyway, if an option is not standardized in POSIX or a similar standard, all bets are off when you move a script to a different platform.